# Trying to make an object with an ID in it

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

For school I am working with a Pokemon API and I am trying to make it that people can type in a Pokemon name and it will show them that pokemon and not the pokemon that I selected for them.

The html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title> Pokemon </title>

    </head>
    <body>        
    <script src="script2.js"></script>



        <h1>PokeDex</h1>
        <div id="poke_container" class="poke-container"></div>
        <div class="pokemon">
        </div>

    </body>


</html>
```

The js code that I got right now is this:

```
const apiData = {
url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/',
type: 'pokemon',
id: 'ditto',
}

const {url, type, id} = apiData

const apiUrl = `${url}${type}/${id}`

fetch(apiUrl)
    .then( (data) => {
        if(data.ok){
            return data.json()
        }
        throw new Error('Response not ok.'); 
    })
    .then( pokemon => generateHtml(pokemon))
    .catch( error => console.error('Error:', error))


const generateHtml = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    const html = `
        <div class="name">${data.name}</div>
        <img src=${data.sprites.front_default}>
        <div class="details">
            <span>Height: ${data.height}</span>
            <span>Weight: ${data.weight}</span>
        </div>
    `
    const pokemonDiv = document.querySelector('.pokemon')
    pokemonDiv.innerHTML = html
}
```

This will show a Ditto but I want it to make it that people can type in something and it will show that Pokemon.

Comment: So what is the problem? What goes wrong? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: Just update the `id` with a value from an input box.

Comment: what you are asking is a little involved - you need: 1. add the input field to your screen, 2. capture when you want the value in it to be processed, usually a button next to it.  handle the button click - get the id value out of the input. -- next you need to restructure your JS - the fetch needs to be called in a controlled fasion.  1. when the page loads - you might want to fetch Ditto as the default. 2 when the button is clicked to search for other pokemon , get the text/id and pass to your new fetch function and use that in your fetch URL.

Comment: @developer ye thats what I am trying but I cant get it to work. can you try solving the code for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

In your html , you need to add an input field for your dynamic pokemon name.

```
<input type="text" id="pokemon">
<button onclick="selectPokemonName()">Submit</button>
```

In your script add this code :

```
function selectPokemonName() {

  var pokemonName = document.getElementById("pokemon").value;

  const apiData = {
  url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/',
  type: 'pokemon',
  id: pokemonName,
  }

const {url, type, id} = apiData

const apiUrl = `${url}${type}/${id}`

fetch(apiUrl)
    .then( (data) => {
        if(data.ok){
            return data.json()
        }
        throw new Error('Response not ok.'); 
    })
    .then( pokemon => generateHtml(pokemon))
    .catch( error => console.error('Error:', error))
}


const generateHtml = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    const html = `
        <div class="name">${data.name}</div>
        <img src=${data.sprites.front_default}>
        <div class="details">
            <span>Height: ${data.height}</span>
            <span>Weight: ${data.weight}</span>
        </div>
    `
    const pokemonDiv = document.querySelector('.pokemon')
    pokemonDiv.innerHTML = html
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Do you also know how to select several pokemons based on what type they are? or how to easy show the first 20 pokemon?

Comment: You can just iterate over your response to show your first 20 Pokemon !

Comment: I dont get what you are trying to make clear? can you edit your code perhaps??